# Как получать данные конкретного экземпляра для формы?

Tags: python, django

Всех приветствую! Начал изучать джанго, и решил написать простенький проект, который реализует CRUD операции над данными из БД. Сделал несколько моделей, форму, все работает отлично. Появилось желание добавить на форму 2 ползунка, которые бы распределяли товар по складам.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    storage1 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    storage2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:product_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

Вот код модели. Как можно увидеть есть поле stock - отвечает за общее количество доступных товаров и поля storage1 и storage2 - количество товаров на 1 и 2 складе соответственно.

```py
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['image', 'name', 'category', 'description', 'price', 'stock', 'available', 'slug', 'storage1', 'storage2']
        widgets = {
            'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'stock': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'available': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}, choices=((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'storage1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'range'}),
            'storage2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'range'})
        }
```

Есть код формы, которую я использую для редактирования и добавления данных.

```py
def update(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = ProductForm(instance=product)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html')

    context={
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'shop/product/update.html', context)
```

И код view, который я использую на странице с обновлением товара.
Так вот, возникло 2 вопроса:

1. Как регулировать min/max значение input range внутри программы? Грубо говоря - общее количество товара - 20, и чтобы пользователь не выбрал кол-во товаров на 1 складе 100 мне необходимо задать максимальное значение ползунка.
2. Как обрабатывать перетягивание ползунка? Из прошлого примера - кол-во товаров 20. Пользователь перетягивает ползунок на втором складе к меньшему значению, соответственно товары на складе должны уменьшаться и должны появляться товары, которые не распределены по складам и которые можно будет распределить на первый склад. Пока что, единственную реализацию которую я вижу это добавление в модель нового поля - unallocated, которое будет вычисляться по формуле: stock - (storage1 + storage2). Но как получать из формы данные, чтобы потом вычислять количество нераспределенных товаров?